# How to hide 'Back to Top' button in script that is only becoming visible after page scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am looking help to hide 'Back to Top' button in script that is only becoming visible after page scroll to the bottom so that I can take screenshots.

I am using below code but still see 'Back to Top' button on my page.

```
if (driver.getPageSource().contains("scroll-to-top"))     
{
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class*='cv-s2t']"));          
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView().style.visibility='hidden'", element);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have it keep removing those as they show up:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  setInterval(() => document.querySelector('.cv-s2t')?.remove(), 100) 
""")
```